# Adding a new column for Summation of values using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, math

I have a data frame. This data frame has a column data named 'Distance'. I Want to create a new column with this title: 'KM'. In each cell of the 'KM' column from the top will follow this formula. I want this formula to be repeated until the last value in the columns.

=KM_i-1 + (0.001 *Ditance_i)

I am looking for a code in Python using Pandas or Numpy
I have added a screenshot of the Excel file to show better:
[image]

Just wondering if anyone could help on writing the code in Python

```
KM=[]
for i in list(range(Toyota_Diesel.shape[0])):
 if i>0:
kilomtr=Toyota_Diesel.loc[i-1,'Distance']+Toyota_Diesel.loc[i,'Distance']
elif i==0:
 kilomtr=Toyota_Diesel['KM']=0
```

Comment: We can *help* if you show us what you've already done. Otherwise we would just be doing it for you, which is not what SO is for. You already know the formula for Excel, try writing it in Python.

Comment: Do you mean `KM[i] - 1` or `KM[i-1]` in your formula?

Comment: KM[i-1] in the formula

Comment: THis is the code that I developed:

Comment: KM=[]

for i in list(range(Toyota_Diesel.shape[0])):
    if i>0:
       #Toyota_Diesel.loc[i,'KM']=Toyota_Diesel.loc[i-1,'Distance']+Toyota_Diesel.loc[i,'Distance']
       kilomtr=Toyota_Diesel.loc[i-1,'Distance']+Toyota_Diesel.loc[i,'Distance']
       
    elif i==0:
         kilomtr=Toyota_Diesel['KM']=0
    KM.append(kilomtr)
     
     
D=DataFrame(KM)
Toyota_Diesel['KM']=KM
print(Toyota_Diesel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to do a cumulative sum across the distance column, and divide it by a constant:

`df['KM'] = df['Distance'].cumsum() * 0.001`